# Environment Variables not being passed with firebase Github CI

Tags: firebase, github, continuous-integration, environment-variables, github-actions

I used `firebase init hosting:github` to set up CI with a react/webpack app i'm making to deploy on push to main.

The problem I am having is that my environment variables are being stored in a .env file for development and the numerous things I have tried to get them to work with the github action of building, and deploying to firebase hosting isn't carrying them across.

I know this because when the action will work successfully and the deployed site will throw errors relevant to missing or invalid API keys that where used saved as environment variables.

**This is what my GitHub workflow (yml) file looks like**

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_API_KEY }} # I have tried using this at the top level and also with the other env scope below.
  
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLUBELO }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: example
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```

Then in my code, I'm just using process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY which works for the development and when I manually run build and deploy to firebase everything works as expected.

**Notes**

- Yes the keys are in Github secrets
- I have checked the obvious spelling mistakes first